# Take Apache httpd.conf back to default after OSX El Capitan update

Tags: php, apache, localhost, httpd.conf, osx-elcapitan

So I did the update to El Capitan on my Imac, all of a sudden anything in my localhost would not respond which I figured was due to the update. I had a search for the el Capitan update affecting apache and saw half a dozen posts with good feedback. I tried a few things, then I tried a few more things until I am now at the point where I can't remember what I commented out/changed in httpd.conf.

apachectl config test is currently throwing out :

Syntax error on line 263 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf:
Invalid command 'Order', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration.

This may be due to the fact I have taken advice from about 20 posts and changed SO much in the file to the point that any change I make just seems to throw another error when I try the config test.

I am now in a place where I need to just take httpd.conf back to its default settings (default being as it where before ANY changes).

I guess the question is whether I can open a text editor and paste in a 'working' httpd.conf then override my current mess of a .conf file or am I better to bite the bullett and return my mac to factory defaults with a fresh (factory) httpd.config file in the directory ?

Please let me know if you have any advice ?

I am able to post my current httpd.config file if that would help ?

Thank you for your help guys !

Comment: please post configuration file

Answer (score 1):

The first question is are you using the Server app provided by Apple or the default install of Apache?

Open the terminal app.

**If this is a standard install of Apache2** (the computer does not have the Server app installed in your Applications folder)

```
cd /etc/apache/
ls -l
```

You should see httpd.conf as well as httpd.conf~previous and other similarly named files. Those would be your older configuration, you can use them to try to restore the functionality of Apache.  e.g. rename httpd.conf and then copy httpd.conf~previous to httpd.conf.  Remember that you must stop/start Apache for the changes to take effect.

**If you have the server app installed, try this.**

```
cd /Library/Server/Web/Config/
ls -l
```

In this folder you would have folders named apache2 and apache2.previous.  You can compared the configurations in each and try to get modules/etc that were being loaded in the old config to run in the new config.  As above, you need to stop/start Apache to have the changes take effect.  In this case you'd open the Server app, pick the Websites option in the sidebar then toggle the button from on to off and back to on.

Do not delete the existing files or move the existing files. Make sure you keep copies of what you touch in case things go badly.  It sounds worse than it really is.

The files may be owned by the root user so you can run this command to give you enough permission to edit files.

```
sudo su
```

It will prompt you for a password, it is usually the same password you use to log into your computer.

Comment: thanks for your time. This is a standard install of Apache2, I managed to bring the httpd.conf file back to the previous. The localhost is now back at /Library/WebServer/Documents but no matter what I do and how ever many tutorials I follow and what I uncomment in httpd.conf, I just can't seem to point it at my Sites folder in the users dir. I have literally been trying to do this since I updated to el Capitan 3 days ago, the previous OSX it was fine and I had no problems, but now I can't get apache to point at my Sites folder. I have created the user.conf file as it should be and chmod 644

Comment: Try cd /etc/apache2/extra then look at httpd-userdir.conf. What does it have in it?

Comment: Everything seems okay... the Include is uncommented :

Include /private/etc/apache2/users/*.conf

<IfModule bonjour_module>

       RegisterUserSite customized-users

</IfModule>